# User friendly URL for separate folder in website in php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a folder (market) in which i have one file called (index.php)
The URL is like this :

> `www.website.com/market/?u=xxx`

I want to make a user friendly URL that looks like this:

> `www.website.com/market/u/xxxx`

In .htaccess file I put this code:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^u/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php?u=$1 [NC, L]
```

I get this response:

```
**Internal Server Error**
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

What did I do wrong here?

> NB: I put the .htaccess file inside the market folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. You need to rewrite and redirect here as per your need what you are trying is only rewrite that's the reason its not working for you.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(market)/\?(u)=([^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2/%3 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^market/(u)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I get the same Internal Server Error

Comment: @RichardBranson, Please do provide information(help me to help you here), which url you are hitting(samples will help here)? Do you have any other rules? If yes then post them too in your htaccess file in your question, please do let me know on these 2 things.

Comment: Im hitting the index.php file which is located on a folder called "market" and I have no other rules than this one. And Also as i've mentionned I put the htaccess file inside the market folder

Comment: @RichardBranson, but your shown samples tells you need to hit `www.website.com/market/u/xxxx` in browser? So you want to hit this in browser `www.website.com/market/?u=xxx` OR `www.website.com/market/u/xxxx` one? Please confirm once.

Comment: Yes! the current URL is www.website.com/market/?u=xxxx And I want to convert it to www.website.com/market/u/xxxx

Comment: @RichardBranson, ok and `www.website.com/market/u/xxxx` should be served by index.php file in backend? Please confirm once like how it should be rewritten in backend, thank you.

Comment: Yes I confirm. the www.website.com/market/u/xxxx should be served by index.php file

Comment: @RichardBranson, ok sure please try my edited rules and make sure your htaccess is in same level where market folder is present(NOT inside market folder besides market folder basically), let me know how it goes then?

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13 ! It's working now :)

Comment: @RichardBranson, Your welcome cheers and happy learning.